# Smoosh iOS SDK startConversation doesn't create user?

Tags: smooch

I have Smooch working with Meya, embedded within my iOS app. When I *send* a message, the user Smooch/Meya user is created as expected. However, when the user does not send a message, and my app only calls startConversation, no user is created.

I've tried it with both calling the login method and not calling the login method.

Here is what I'm doing now:

```
Smooch.initWith(settings) { (error: Error?, _: [AnyHashable: Any]?) in
  if error == nil {
    Smooch.login("\(id)", jwt: jwt) { (error: Error?, _: [AnyHashable: Any]?) in
      if error == nil {
        print("login complete")
        Smooch.startConversation { (error: Error?, _: [AnyHashable: Any]?) in
          if error == nil {
            print("started conversation")
          }
        }
    } else {
      print("error logging in")
      print(error)
    }
  }
}
```

And this results in the following log:

```
login complete
started conversation
```

I have done a request to the get appusers endpoint and I see that `"conversationStarted":true`, however, no user has been created in Meya.ai.

Comment: Can you confirm that there is no error returned in the callback to `startConversation`? Also keep in mind that if the current user already has a conversation, the call will be a no-op.

You can confirm if a user was created by inspecting the `appUserId` property on the `SKTUser.currentUser` instance, and doing a [get appUser](https://docs.smooch.io/rest/#get-app-user) call with that ID, or create a webhook with the `conversation:start` trigger and see if it fires in response to the `startConversation` call

Comment: @michaels I've edited the post. Thank you for the help. You'll see that I've nowdone a request to the get appusers endpoint and I see that `"conversationStarted":true`, however, no user has been created in Meya.ai. So that seems to be where the disconnect is.

Comment: @michaels I did a call to the businesssystems api endpoint for that app users and confirmed the response is `{"businessSystems":[]}`

Comment: After further investigation, I've determined that Meya doesn't show up as a business system, rather its just installed as a Webhooks in the Smooch application. And viewing the Webhook in the API confirms it only has the following triggers:` "triggers":["postback","message:appUser","conversation:read","delivery:success","delivery:failure"]`

Comment: The Meya integration is actually maintained by Meya itself and was not built by Smooch, I suppose you would need to submit a feature request with their team for them to support the `conversation:start` trigger

Comment: @michaels I received a response from Meya support confirming that they don't current support `conversation:start`. For now, I've put a workaround in place in the iOS app to call startConversation and then if the message count is 0, send a small message, which does get passed to Meya and properly creates the user. Not ideal, but good enough to move forward with for now. Thanks for the help.